# "How to fix" 'Cant give more values to the variable' Python3

Tags: python-3.x

"I want to use the statement break, and also in case the condition is not True, to give some values to a new variable. The thing is, Python uses only one line, and still runs after i've inserted a number.

```py
prompt = '\nDime tu edad y te dire el precio de tu entrada .'
prompt += '\n¿Cual es tu edad?'

while True:
    edad = input(prompt)
    edad = int(edad)
    if edad < 3:
        break
    elif edad > 3: ## Here I'm trying to set the conditions as to give a new value to precio.
        precio = '5€'
    elif edad > 12:
        precio = '10€'
    elif edad > 18:
        precio = '15€'
    print(f" El precio es {precio}")
```

Comment: Why can't you *give some values to a new variable* before `break`?

Comment: Just a note: Your code will *never* enter the `elif edad > 12` or `elif edad > 18` blocks. The `elif` block is only entered if the condition is `True` **AND** if none of the previous/connected `if/elif` statements evaluated to `True`. Another note: What happens when `edad == 3`?

Comment: Would it go through if i use a flag?. Yeah didnt think about that, ill just put ' <= 3'.

Comment: What do you mean by flag?

Comment: A variable that's either True or False, depending on the conditions that i set

Comment: Second question, what do you mean by "python only uses one line"